# Making a field function generic

Tags: c++, function, generics, field

I've made a non-generic function to write out everything in a field but I want to make it generic so it can use any type of field. But everywhere I look I get very confused of how to do this.
Note: I translated the code to english for better understanding, so if any of those are keywords it doesn't matter in my code.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

void writeOutField(int *a, int length)
{
     for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
     {
         cout << a[i] << endl;
     }
}



int main()
{
    int intField[6] = {9, 7, 5, 3, 1};
    string stringField[4] = {"Kalle", "Eva", "Nisse"};
    writeOutField(intField, 5); //Works with the non-generic version.
    writeOutField(stringField, 3); //Is what I want to make work.
    system("pause");
}
```

Comment: By generics, do you mean templates?

Comment: `writeOutField(stringField, 3);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Templates are used to write generic functions:

```
template <typename T>
void writeOutField(T const *a, int length) // const is optional, but a good idea
{
    // your function body here
}
```

This can be called for any type with a suitable `<<` overload.

```
writeOutField(intField, 5);    // Works: int is streamable
writeOutField(stringField, 3); // Works: string is also streamable
```

Answer (score 1):

Converting your function into a template is easy:

```
template <typename T>
void writeOutField(T *a, int length)
{
     for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
     {
         cout << a[i] << endl;
     }
}
```

See also [Function template](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/function_template) or a good book on C++ which describes templates, e.g. [The C++ Programming Language](http://www.stroustrup.com/4th.html).

Answer (score 1):

Use templates for generic functions. Here is working code:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

template<class T>
void writeOutField(T *a, int length)
{
     for(int i=0; i<length; i++)
     {
         cout << a[i] << endl;
     }
}



int main()
{
    int intField[6] = {9, 7, 5, 3, 1};
    string stringField[4] = {"Kalle", "Eva", "Nisse"};
    writeOutField<int>(intField, 5); //Works with the non-generic version.
    writeOutField<string>(stringField, 3); //Is what I want to make work.
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
template <class X> void writeOutField(T *a,int length) {
...
cout << a[i] << endl;
...
}
```